# Can't find /dev/video on MacBook

Tags: webcam, macbook, devices

I installed ubuntu 19.10 on my MacBook and tried to use the integrated webcam of MacBook, but when using `ls /dev/video*` I can't get any device. On my other laptop I can get `/dev/video0` which is the integrated webcam of the laptop. I don't know whether it is the problem of the drivers, because the webcam of my MacBook can detect brightness of environment.
How can I solve the issue?

Comment: I'm facing similar situation and looking for a solution.